# How to turn off WebStorm auto-suggestions

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I can't figure out how to turn off these suggestions:

[image]

Anybody know what the name of those suggestions is?

Comment: Check out this [page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205823059-Can-I-disable-annoying-tooltips-suggestion-Alt-Enter-) to learn how to disable these tooltips

Answer (score 2):

You can disable TypeScript auto-imports completely, by clearing `Add TypeScript imports automatically` checkbox in `Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import` - import suggestions will be available on explicit `Alt+Enter` on the reference. If you'd like to disable import suggestions for particular statement only, you can add `// noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable` comment above it

Answer (score 0):

These suggestions are came from `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> TypeScript`. Uncheck those suggestions if you don't need it.